# Клиент не отправляет некоторые secure cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, сеть, axios, react-hook

После 'авторизации' сервер присылает мне ответ с тремя httpOnly куками, но при попытке отправить ему следующий запрос, включающий эти куки он почему то отправляет только куки с сессией, а куки с токенами игнорирует. С чем это может быть связано?

Ответ от сервера посте 'авторизации':

> access-control-allow-credentials: true
> access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
> Connection: keep-alive content-length: 26
> content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2023
> 13:54:30 GMT Keep-Alive: timeout=72 set-cookie: sessionId=;
> Domain=0.0.0.0; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 03 Apr 2023 13:54:30 GMT;
> HttpOnly set-cookie:
> access-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NDI4YjNiNDgzMDRmNDZiMGM2ZTI3NjIiLCJzZXNzaW9uVG9rZW4iOiIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODA1MzAwNjl9.ZBOz7sGhijnKYskhMOrPEatOFQee3XNTNhgFSem9KWU;
> Domain=0.0.0.0; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 03 Apr 2023 13:55:29 GMT;
> HttpOnly set-cookie:
> refresh-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uVG9rZW4iOiIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODA1MzAwNjl9.TwBU5pM0Bdd6JQdciadWDw21ONY4xZSUh6Yt6FpMHZ4;
> Domain=0.0.0.0; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 10 Apr 2023 13:54:29 GMT;
> HttpOnly set-cookie:
> sessionId=AfSQmruYXOC-e_HEDJ9rrnpW0Gaa4WP9.r5tTx72UOz0U2%2F0J5UVi01i6iZ4u7dnjgG5V6OO8e%2BM; Path=/; HttpOnly vary: Origin

Следующий запрос к серверу:

> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* Accept-Encoding: gzip,
> deflate, br Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Connection: keep-alive Cookie:
> sessionId=KGJYo6fH8N_ZcuxxfIX01Cmzoi1aOdw5.swGXHnbgAZ704EjGcfbrRyjrwEVcLP2P8isAukr0lB8
> Host: localhost:8001 Origin: http://localhost:3000 Referer:
> http://localhost:3000/ sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111",
> "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111" sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
> sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows" Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty Sec-Fetch-Mode:
> cors Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Запрос отправляю с с помощью axios c флагом withCredentials: true
Декларация фетчера:

```
export function useAxiosGetFetcher ({
  protocol = 'http',
  host = HOST,
  port = PORT,
  api = 'api',
  route = 'me',
  options = { 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      
    },
    withCredentials: true
}} = {}) {

  const fetcher = async () => {
      const url = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}/${api}/${route}`
      return axios
          .get(url, options)
              .then(response => response.data)
               
  } 
  return {fetcher}
}
```

Использование axios фетчера:

```
export function useUser() {

    const api = 'api/users'
    const route = 'me'
    const key = `${api}/${route}`

    const {fetcher} = useAxiosGetFetcher({ api, route })

    const { data: user, 
        error,
        isValidating,
        mutate } = useSWR<User>(key, fetcher)

    return {user, error, isValidating, mutate}
}
```

Comment: А куки кто отправляет? Там какой-то дата немножко в прошлом 13:55 GMT уже прошло

Comment: `Expires=Mon, 03 Apr 2023 13:54:30 GMT` — дата в прошлом; `Domain=0.0.0.0` — неадекватный домен у куки

Comment: Куки отправляет сервер, в продакшн версии он сам использует next через плагин, но чтобы писать клиент быстрее я также дополнительно использую автономную версию клиента, который обращается к серверу с другого порта. Сервер работает на порту 8001, клиент на 3000. Предполагаю что проблема сейчас именно с CORS. Похоже браузер просто не хочет сохранять эти куки. На сервере cookieOptions сейчас создаются с опциями, htmlOnly=true, secure=false, sameDomain='lax'

Comment: Не хочет из-за некорректных Expires и Domain

Comment: Благодарю, поправлю.